# Disable user resize a form after specific size

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0

I would like to let users resize my form but when they reach a specific size to disable this ability to make it smaller window than i want.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the [`MinimumSize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.minimumsize.aspx) property of the form to the minimum size you want to enforce.

There is also a mirror property [`MaximumSize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.maximumsize.aspx) (mentioned for completeness).

Comment: @AlwaysBeCoding - many times we can't see the woods for the forest. There are so many properties on Form, that missing some is easy.

Answer (score 3):

Set the `MinimumSize` property on your form. This will prevent the user from making the form any smaller than this value. Similarly, you can set the `MaximumSize` property to ensure that they cannot make it any larger than that value.

Answer (score 1):

Set the form's [`MinimumSize` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.minimumsize.aspx) in the designer.

Answer (score 1):

Set the form's [MinimumSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.minimumsize.aspx) property to the smallest size you want to allow.